# How to avoid global variables?

Tags: javascript

I've been told not to use global variables.

I use one to turn off/on client side validation.

I use two more to conrol me drop-down menu.

If these should not be gloval variables where should I put them?

/*
Global
*/

```
var client_validation=1,  // used to turn off/on client-side validation
    menu_timer=0,
    menu_elment=0;
window.onload=i0;

/*menu*/

function top_mouse_over(id)
  {
  bottom_mouse_over();
  if(menu_element)menu_element.style.visibility='hidden';
  menu_element=document.getElementById(id);
  menu_element.style.visibility='visible';
  }
function internal_time()
  {
  if(menu_element)menu_element.style.visibility='hidden';
  }
function mouse_out()
  {
  menu_timer=window.setTimeout(internal_time, 500);
  }
function bottom_mouse_over()
  {
  if(menu_timer)
    {
    window.clearTimeout(menu_timer);
    menu_timer=0;
    }
  }



Header 1  // This makes more sense
  Content

Header 1  // Than this
Content
```

Comment: On an unrelated comment: though you use your indention style consistently, I find it even harder to read than the Gnu style. That is a very un-JS-y style to indent.

Comment: IMO putting the code inside the braces at the same level as the braces themselves is the main reason for the poor readability.

Comment: `window.onload=i0;` was fine the way you had it. Do not change it to a `window_onload` property on the `globalControls` like in that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you those might be good candidates for globals. Globals are supposed to, well, be reserved for operations with broad implications for the app like controlling fundamental behavior across multiple pieces.

Now, if you want to create a "namespace" for them, it's this simple:

```
var globalControls = {
    client_validation:1,
    menu_timer:0,
    menu_elment:0,
    window_onload:i0
};
```

Javascript doesn't have real namespaces yet. Objects are used as a substitute for them until the next version of ECMAScript might get around to adding that feature.

Comment: menu_element:0; should have a comma after it?

Comment: Yes, a comma, that was just a typo (fixed). @Mike - why do you change the `window.onload=i0;` statement from the question to a `window_onload` property on your object?

Comment: I changed it to window_onload to make it look like another configuration flag. No real purpose other than that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about javascript namespacing.

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The title should be "How do I avoid global variables"? But that's ok.

You can create an object and assign properties to it. Then you'll have variables inside an object and these variables will only be accessible through this one, not through the global scope.

Example:

```
var config = {
    clientValidation: true,
    menuTimer: 0,
    menuElement: 0,
    someFunction: function () {
        // alert (this.clientValidation) "this" is the object scope
    }
};
// then you access the object properties:
alert( config.clientValidation ); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

namespacing separates class definitions from colliding, however, it will not solve the global variable problem.  It is a temporary fix.

A solution to global variables is to use a class instance which encapsulates properties that would otherwise be global.  Encapsulation is one of the 3 pillars of object oriented programming.

See for an example of a class with a namespace that has encapsulated properties.
Additionally, I show how to create a custom jquery plugin that uses the class.
http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/javascript-development/Automatically-generate-the-table-of-contents-with-jQuery

When i have data that i need persisted that would normally require creating a global variable I instead use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ to attach the data in an object form to the dom element making use of this data.